# ajax Javascript search button not working in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, ajax, codeigniter, search, button

I am new to php and codeigniter. The problem is when i click on search button it doesn't get text box data. i put alert to get show text box data in ajax but it show me  {"data":false}

This is the view

```
<form action="/index.php/search/define" method=GET>
    Word: <input type=text id="textbox" name="result1" onkeyup="demo(this.value);" />
    <input type="button" name="all"  id ="btnclicksearch" value="Search" />


    <div id="mydiv"></div>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript" src="/site/assets/themes/default/js/demo.js">
```

This is the js file

var xmlhttp;

```
function demo(t)
{
    // note - this doesn't work in IE browsers - surprised?
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // now build the URL of the server-side resource we want to
    // communicate with
    var url = "/site/index.php/search/returnsearchresults?t=" + t;
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = myfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

$('#btnclicksearch').click(function () {
            var url = "/site/index.php/search/returnsearch" ;

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: $("#textbox").val(),
                dataType: "text", 
                cache:false,
                success: function (data) {
                     alert(data);
                    $('#mydiv').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

controller text box

```
 public function returnsearchresults()
    {
        $typed = $this->input->get('t');
        if ($typed == null || $typed == '') {
            echo ''; // send back nothing if we got nothing
            exit;
        }
        $this->load->model('Search_model');
         $data['result1'] = $this->Search_model->match_model($typed);
        $this->load->view('content/word_view',$data);
    }
```

contoller button

```
 public function returnsearch()
    {
         $data = array(
  'data' => $this->input->post('title'),
     );
}
```

Comment: what is the demo function do?

Comment: a POST requires key/value pairs to be sent. You are only sending a value so controller will see empty $_POST in php

Comment: data.... u need s key for this $("#textbox").val()

Comment: I added the demo function it's retriving the data as suggetions

Comment: Where's the code for php-page that does the search?

Comment: I added the demo function it's retrieving all the matching data from database as suggestions.It's not alert data .Please can any one point me out how to parse data by key

Comment: When i typing data it retrive all possible data but after i select one and put it to text box and click search button it not load the selected item giving me data: false